# Ubuntu 21.10 : Unable to install php 7.4

Tags: software-installation, php, 21.10

I tried to install php 7.4 on latest version of Ubuntu 21.10 but fail.

```
$ sudo apt install php7.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4'
```

Thanks

Comment: The default PHP package for 21.10 is 8.0, and there is no third-party repository (yet) that offers 7.4 for this latest interim release of Ubuntu. One option might be to use a VM with an older version of Ubuntu or a Docker container with some proxying to route traffic from the host.